# Django Nginx: Why doesn't my app follow MEDIA_ROOT?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, imagefield

I have a Django project with the following static and media settings in settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have it running with Nginx and Gunicorn but when I upload an image using the admin page, the MEDIA_ROOT setting is not respected.. It actually makes a media directory in a different folder. What could be causing this?

Comment: Did you restart/reload your server after you updated your code?

Comment: It's better to keep media files outside your /static/ folder: `MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')`